# How can I get autocompletion for JavaFX CSS properties in VS Code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, javafx

I used to write CSS JavaFX on NetBeans 8 (JavaFX 8), but autocompletion "-fx" CSS prefix is no longer available on Apache NetBeans 17 with JavaFX17. I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.77 on Linux with JavaFX 17 and Java JDK 17 Coretto, but that does not seem to have it either. Is there a way to enable JavaFX CSS autocompletion?

[image: vscode css]

Comment: Autocompletion of CSS, including the JavaFX flavor, works in Idea, but I think [only in the paid version](https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce), the rest of JavaFX development functionality in Idea such as project creation wizards and FXML support is included in the free community edition.

Comment: @user Sorry for confusion I don't know how autocomplete is defined in VSCode.  I assumed it would need to parse to work out how to autocomplete to know what options available where.

Comment: @user But I guess the core CSS parser is kind of sufficient and you can gain some autocomplete by defining the `-fx` CSS attributes in the custom data format json which would provide the ability to autocomplete `-fx` CSS attributes.  I guess it wouldn't be aware enough to provide only the attributes applicable in a given context, like knowing `-fx-background` only applies to regions and not text, or understanding looked-up colors or linear gradient format options, which I would normally expect in an intelligent editor, but probably the custom data format is an easy way to get some support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Announcement: someone has used this answer post and applied it to create a VS Code extension: [`bernardoamorim7.javafx-css-support-vscode`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bernardoamorim7.javafx-css-support-vscode). I have no affiliation with this extension, and make no promises about its correctness or whether it will be kept up to date as new CSS properties are added. Just an FYI that it exists and that you may find it convenient to use rather than doing the manual setup I explain below.

---

You can get something basic going with [VS Code's CSS Custom Data facility](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/blob/main/docs/customData.md). This facility is pretty limited. It doesn't seem to currently have a way to restrict allowable values for each custom property <sup><sub>([cssLanguageTypes.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/blob/main/src/cssLanguageTypes.ts) mentions `restrictions` and `values` fields, but those aren't in the customdata JSON schema for reasons I don't know)</sub></sup>, and it doesn't seem to have a way to restrict what selectors a property is relevant for (but then again, I don't think VS Code's builtin CSS has such a feature anyway).

Create a file in your workspace named something like "javafx-css-vscode-customdata.json", and in it, put the following:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/raw/main/docs/customData.schema.json",
  "version": 1.1,
  "properties": [

  ]
}
```

Then open the CSS Reference documentation for the version of JavaFX that you are using (Ex. https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), and run the following JavaScript code in your browser's devtools:

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll("tr:has(th.propertyname)")]
  .filter(tr => tr.children[0].textContent.startsWith("-fx-"))
  .map(tr => {
    const clean = c => c.textContent.trim().replaceAll("\"","\\\"").replaceAll(/\n +/g," ");
    const descParts = [...tr.children].slice(1).map(clean);
    const headers = [...tr.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("thead > tr").children].slice(1).map(clean);
    const description = headers.map((header,index) => `${header}: ${descParts[index]}`).join("\\n\\n");
    return `{\n  "name": "${tr.children[0].textContent}",\n  "description": "${description}"\n}`;
  })
  .join(",\n")
);
```

Copy the output of that code and paste it into the `properties` array in the customdata JSON file.

Then, in your [workspace's `.vscode/settings.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson), put the following:

```json
"css.customData": [
   "./javafx-css-vscode-customdata.json"
]
```

Here's an example of part of the output of the above script:

```json
{
  "name": "-fx-opacity",
  "description": "**Values**: <number>\n\n**Default**: 1\n\n**Range**: [0.0 ... 1.0]\n\n**Comments**: Opacity can be thought of conceptually as a postprocessing operation. Conceptually, after the node (including its descendants) is rendered into an RGBA offscreen image, the opacity setting specifies how to blend the offscreen rendering into the current composite rendering."
},
```

You may need to restart VS Code to see your new changes take effect.

I'd include an example customdata JSON file, but it would be too big to fit within Stack Exchange's post size limit.

Note that if you just want the properties to not have "unrecognized property" warnings, then you can use the `css.lint.validProperties` setting.

Comment: very well explained , I followed step by step and it works (vscode Version: 1.77.1)

Comment: There is an extension for this now:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bernardoamorim7.javafx-css-support-vscode